# how can i create a dynamic class in c#(silverlight) where i can loop through properties

Tags: c#, silverlight, reflection, loops, properties

Here is my code:

```
ObservableCollection<object> ll = new ObservableCollection<object>();

public MainPage(){ 

InitializeComponent();

 ll= createobj(x2);

        dataGrid2.ItemsSource = ll;
```

this is the function that creates my properties.
how can I make them public?

```
 private PropertyInfo papa(string propertyName, TypeBuilder tb, Type tt){ 


 private PropertyInfo papa(string propertyName, TypeBuilder tb, Type tt){   
 FieldBuilder ff = tb.DefineField("_" + propertyName, tt, FieldAttributes.Public);
PropertyBuilder pp =
            tb.DefineProperty(propertyName,
                             PropertyAttributes.None ,
                             tt,
                             new Type[] {tt });


        MethodBuilder mget =
           tb.DefineMethod("get_value",
                                        MethodAttributes.Public,
                                      tt,
                                       Type.EmptyTypes);

        ILGenerator currGetIL = mget.GetILGenerator();
        currGetIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
        currGetIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, ff);
        currGetIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);


        MethodBuilder mset =
            tb.DefineMethod("set_value",
                                       MethodAttributes.Public,
                                       null,
                                       new Type[] { tt });


        ILGenerator currSetIL = mset.GetILGenerator();
        currSetIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
        currSetIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
        currSetIL.Emit(OpCodes.Stfld, ff);
        currSetIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);


        pp.SetGetMethod(mget);
        pp.SetSetMethod(mset);
        return pp;
    }
```

this is the function that creates my object

```
 private ObservableCollection<object> createobj(XDocument xx){

        AssemblyName assemblyName = new AssemblyName();
        assemblyName.Name = "tmpAssembly";
        AssemblyBuilder assemblyBuilder = Thread.GetDomain().DefineDynamicAssembly(assemblyName, AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run);
        ModuleBuilder module = assemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicModule("tmpModule");


        TypeBuilder tb = module.DefineType("SilverlightApplication20.blabla", TypeAttributes.Public | TypeAttributes.Class);
        int[] exista={0,0};
        PropertyInfo pp;

        foreach (XElement node in xx.Root.Descendants())
        {
            foreach (XAttribute xa in node.Attributes())
            {
                if (xa.Name.ToString() != "rind" && xa.Name.ToString() != "col")
                    pp = papa(xa.Name.ToString(), tb, typeof(string));
                else
                  pp = papa(xa.Name.ToString(), tb, typeof(int));

            }
        }

        pp=papa("nume",tb,typeof(string));
        pp = papa("parinte", tb, typeof(string));
        Type gg = tb.CreateType();

        ObservableCollection<object> collection = new ObservableCollection<object>();

        PropertyInfo[] pps = gg.GetProperties( );

        foreach (XElement node in xx.Root.Descendants())
        {
            object obiect = Activator.CreateInstance(gg);
            foreach (PropertyInfo property in pps)
            {  if (property.Name == "nume" )
                    property.SetValue(obiect, node.Name.ToString(),null);
            if (property.Name == "parinte")
                property.SetValue(obiect, node.Parent.Name.ToString(), null);
            } 
            foreach (XAttribute xa in node.Attributes())
            {
                  string value="";
                 int value2=0;
                { if(xa.Name.ToString()!="rind" && xa.Name.ToString()!="col")
                  value = xa.Value;
                else
                   value2 = int.Parse( xa.Value);

                    foreach (PropertyInfo property in pps)
                    {
                        if (property.Name == xa.Name.ToString())
                        {
                            if(xa.Name.ToString()=="rind" || xa.Name.ToString()=="col")
                                property.SetValue(obiect, value2, null);
                            else
                            property.SetValue(obiect, value, null);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }

            } collection.Add(obiect);
        }
        return collection;

    }
```

the problem is that I can't loop through the properties.

I would like to create something like this:

```
  public class blabla
  {
  public int property1{get;set;}
  public int property2{get;set;}

  }
```

and be able to do something like this

```
   object1.property=1;
```

this is what i need:
I have a xml string that looks like this:

```
                     <xml>
                    <col1 label="label1" r="1" c="1"/>
                    <col2 label="label2" r="2" c="1"/>
                    <col3 label="label2" r="2" c="2"/>

                                             < /xml>
```

i want to bind it to a datagrid.
the problem is that i don't know how many attributes i will have at runtime.

for the above example i could create a class like this:

```
  public class blabla
  {
  public string labe{get;set;}
  public int r{get;set;}
  public int c{get;set;}
   }
```

but as I said there can be many more attributes. that's why I need something dynamically.
At the same time I need to be able to iterate through the properties created

Comment: Why do use `objects` instead of your `blabla` class? What are you trying to do??

Comment: a dynamic class. I have a string xml and I want to create a dynamic class with those properties(attributes in xml)

Comment: This really looks like a **bad** approach. You should edit your answer and give us much more background about your needs, I'm sure we'll be able to give you a more reasonable way to go.

Comment: What do you hope to gain from this rather than using a dictionary or an expando (dynamic) object?

Comment: i can't use a dictionary because i can't bind it to a datagrid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, you are trying to bind a collection of objects to a datagrid where you don't know what the object will look like at compile-time.

This blog post adresses that issue:
http://blog.bodurov.com/How-to-Bind-Silverlight-DataGrid-From-IEnumerable-of-IDictionary/

If I misunderstood your question, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I would say your best bet would be to transform the source XML to a DataSet or an IEnumerable and then bind that to your grid.